# 2D LLVM array manipulation using the `llvm` Haskell library

Tags: haskell, llvm

I am toying with the [llvm](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-3.0.0.0) Haskell package to generate LLVM IR code. Consider the following 2D aggregate LLVM array. It is an array of length 2 of arrays of length 4 of 8-bit integers.

```
[2 x [4 x i8]]
```

I have tried putting together a simple exercise, but I'm stuck. I'd like to go increment the value of each element in my array.

```
{- input 2D array

[ [1 , 2 , 3 , 4]
, [5 , 6 , 7 , 8] ]

-}

{- desired output 2D array

[ [3 , 4 , 5 , 6 ]
, [7 , 8 , 9 , 10] ]

-}
```

The challenge: to implement the nested `forLoop`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module TwoDArray where

import Data.Int
import Data.Word
import LLVM.Core
import LLVM.Util.Loop
import Data.TypeLevel (D2,D4)

f :: CodeGenModule (Function (IO ()))
f = createNamedFunction ExternalLinkage "test" $ do
        let xss = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
            height = 2
            width  = 4
        let arr = Array $ map Array xss :: Array D2 (Array D4 Word8)
        (ptr :: Value (Ptr (Array D2 (Array D4 Word8)))) <- malloc
        store (valueOf arr) ptr
        forLoop (valueOf 0) (valueOf (fromIntegral height) :: Value Int32) () $ \ h () -> do
           forLoop (valueOf 0) (valueOf (fromIntegral width) :: Value Int32) () $ \ w () -> do
             {- 1. load element at <h/w> position in 2D array arr -}
             {- 2. add 2 to the value as y -}
             {- 3. put value of y in to position <h/w> in 2D array arr -}
             ret ()
           ret ()
        return () -- better still, return the pointer `ptr`
```

Comment: If you're willing to work with the new ``llvm-general`` bindings then I've written a similar "for" loop abstraction in the ``llvm-codegen`` package. Still experimental, but looks similar to what you want to do: https://github.com/sdiehl/llvm-codegen/blob/master/test/Saxpy.hs#L37

Answer (score 1):

Btw. I started the package [knead](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/knead) for array processing using LLVM, though it is not very mature so far.
The package provides a DSL for array processing similar to Accelerate. Actually I wrote it with adding it as back-end to Accelerate in mind.
Your simple example could be expressed by a 'map' over the array.